# How to allow SQL Server Express to use multiple cores?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I am currently doing load testing and sqlservr.exe during peak times is using only up to 50% of CPU.

Is there a way to force Sql Server to use more than 50% of CPU?

I am running virtual machine on GoGrid with 2GBs of RAM (2 cores), SQL Server is Express Edition 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since 50% of the CPU is one core, you're really asking how to make it use both cores.  Please **update** your title.

Comment: I think you're making an unfounded assumption that SQL Server could get things done faster if it could use more than that 50%. Kind of like saying I could drive from point A to point B faster if I could use both lanes of this highway.

Comment: @S.Lott: The question is valid for systems with more than two cores, and the answer applies equally to such systems, so IMHO this title is fine: it'll help anyone using SQL Express to get the (disappointing) news quickly and easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Server Express edition is [limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#Editions) to a single processor.

Edit: [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143760.aspx)

Comment: It can use different cores, just one at a time.  If processor 1 is busy it can use processor 2, it just won't use them both a the same time.

Comment: I think it's fairly clear that the question is about using more than one core simultaneously.

Comment: @jvanderh http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/06/10/sql-server-2008-express-rc0.aspx "SQL Express will take advantage of multiple cores on the single CPU by starting a scheduler for each core." My understanding is that it would be able to use two or more cores in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the virtual machine is set to use all available cpu cores.